# Using angular-cli in hybrid app

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli

My team and I want to use angular-cli in our project,
Our client app is hybrid app (angular.js with angular 5)
We encounter several problems.
So first of all before trying to find solution...is at all possible to use angular-cli in hybrid app?
If so...where can we find guide to the correct integration?

Comment: Did you read the docs? - https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#bootstrapping-hybrid-applications

Comment: When you say hybrid, it's better you are using different folders, ex. 'angular' and `angularjs` inside different folders. If not, you'll have tons of trouble. Because they support very different build system. The main issue is `package.json`

Comment: @windmaomao not at all. Once bundled, the package file disappears into vendor files. That's not an issue. The real issue is to combine both applications in one URL, in that you're right. I would not recommend doing that, and truthfully I don't know how one could achieve (or want to achieve) that.

Comment: @trichetriche, what I mean is that you can't have two different copy of content inside `package.json`. He's not building a library inside a framework, he's trying to blend two framework together. The `package.json` file can't be copied around.

Comment: You can have either one or two package files. If one, you will need to be very careful about the versions and dependencies, and I agree it's complicated, but it's possible. With two, this becomes easier, but it's still very complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. I used Angular CLI for hybrid app and followed this [link](https://joelbinn.gitbooks.io/hybrid-angular-angularjs-application-with-angular/content/ch1-making-the-hybrid.html). However I encountered many issues but finally I was able to use Angular CLI. Please let me know if you need any help or guidance.

Comment: I owe you a coffee. I have lost a lot of time with angular tutorial and with tons of Medium tutorials without success, whereas your works fine! I had some adjustment because I am working with angular-cli version 8.